# Extracting category ID of an entry and then using it to display more entries

Tags: channel-entries, categories, query

I'm wondering what the best way to do this may be. I probably haven't worded the question in the best way so I'll explain.

Basically, I have an entry on page which is assigned to a category. On the page I'd like to be able to display other entries assigned to the same category. Sort of a 'similar projects' concept. This needs to be done dynamically however.

My hunch is that I may need to use a query to first pull through the category id of the current entry being shown, then use that value in the `category=""` parameter.

Can anyone point me in the right direction with this

```
{exp:query sql="SELECT cat_id FROM exp_channel_data"}

{exp:channel:entries
 channel="projects"
 dynamic="off"
 category="{cat_id}"}

  {title}

{/exp:channel:entries}          
{/exp:query}
```

Maybe something like this but I'm really unsure. Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apologies, I have just seen the `related_categories_mode="yes"` parameter.

Problem solved.

Comment: Please, Adam, mark your answer as right. Thank you!

Comment: Can't mark my own answer for another 23 hours so I'm being told. Will mark it ASAP though